# Window on desktop / bottom-most window in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I'm trying to launch a form at startup and have it remain as the background for my application the entire time its running.  Essentially I want to hide all the desktop icons and have a blank background. Further, when a user clicks certain buttons I want the form BackColor to change.

I've searched a bunch and I keep finding half solutions.  Here is what I've tried so far:

Created a BackBaseForm that overides the WndProc event and if its `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, I don't call `base.WndProc(ref m)` and instead send the following message:

`SetWindowPos(Handle, new IntPtr(1), 0, 0, this.width, this.height, SWP_NOZORDER);`

However, whenever I click on form it still brings it to the front. I also tried creating a `WINDOWPOS` struct, marshalling the pointer to the struct, then modifying the struct. I don't think that this changes the actual `lParam` in the message though.

Answer (score 0):

Create background form and set owner form of your 'main' form to that background form. For example:

```
frmBackground backgroundForm = new frmBackground();
frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
mainForm.Owner = backgroundForm;
backgroundForm.Show();
mainForm.Show();
```

Comment: There will be many forms launching from several different assemblies, will this work for that?

Comment: It doesn't matter in which assemblies form classes are, as long as all windows are in same process. Even when in different processes you should be able to do this but you'll need to use some lower level Win32 API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Set `frmBackground.Enabled` to false.

In your mainform:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        var bg = new Form();
        bg.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        bg.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        bg.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        bg.Show();
        bg.Enabled = false;
        this.Owner = bg; // optional - see below
    }
```

If you do this:

```
this.Owner = f;
```

Then your main form border will flash when you click the background form (at least in Windows 7, I'm not sure about other versions). Either way, setting Enabled to false will work. But you'll get a beep when you click the background form, which may be annoying. There's probably some way to prevent it.